# Why is xcopy command not working for copying a bitmap file into a subdirectory of Windows system32 directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a problem with my batch file. I want to copy some files using `xcopy`, but it isn't working.

```
@echo off
md %systemroot%\system32\hello
md %systemroot%\system32\wlppr
xcopy /y "%cd%\qwerty.bmp" "%systemroot%\system32\hello"
xcopy /y "%cd%\qwerty2.bmp" "%systemroot%\system32\wlppr"
```

The folders create succesfully, but when Windows tries to copy files this message appears in CMD:

```
File not found - qwerty.bmp
0 File(s) copied
File not found - qwerty2.bmp
0 File(s) copied
```

And yes, I tried to run the file with administrator privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you enable `echo on` to see the actual commands issued?

Comment: Run your script **As administrator** in order to have write access to the protected system32 directory. I know you mentioned admin privileges but humour us anyway.

Comment: Since you are writing to the system directory you need to run the script as admin.  But when you do that the working directory becomes system32 and then it can no longer find your files.

Comment: does `"%cd%\qwerty.bmp"` exist? - please display the actual value `echo "%cd%\qwerty.bmp"` and verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By double clicking on a batch file the Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` is executed with using implicitly option `/C` to close the console window automatically and terminate the command process when batch processing is finished after successful execution or an exit because of a syntax error. This behavior is not good for debugging a batch file not working as expected. Better for debugging a batch file is opening a command prompt window resulting in running `cmd.exe` with using implicitly option `/K` to keep open the console window and let the command process continue running after executing a command like a batch file (not containing `exit` without `/B`) to view all error messages output during execution of the batch file.

Double clicking on a batch file results usually in executing the batch file in the directory of the batch file. For that reason the current directory is the directory of the batch file.

But if the batch file is stored on a network share opened in Windows Explorer with a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention), Windows command interpreter outputs **usually** a message that the current directory is set to `%SystemRoot%` before executing the first command line from batch file. This behavior can be turned off via a special Windows registry value.

And if the batch file is executed with right clicking on it and using context menu option **Run as administrator**, the Windows command process is started with `%SystemRoot%\System32` as current directory resulting in executing the batch file with the Windows system directory as current directory.

So it is advisable to write this batch file to work independent on current directory. A good idea would be to put the two bitmap files to copy into same directory as the batch file and use `%~dp0` to reference the directory of the batch file independent on what is the current directory on execution of the batch file. `%~dp0` references drive and path of argument 0 which is the name of the batch file. Run `call /?` in a command prompt window for details on referencing batch file arguments.

The command **XCOPY** creates automatically the entire folder tree on copying 1 or more files if the target string ends with a backslash making it clear for `xcopy` that the target is a folder name and not a file name.

So the commands to use are:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~dp0qwerty.bmp" "%SystemRoot%\System32\hello\" /Q /Y >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~dp0qwerty2.bmp" "%SystemRoot%\System32\wlppr\" /Q /Y >nul
```

The folder path of batch file referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash. Therefore no additional backslash is specified in both source file name strings.

Run in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` for help on this command.